# Memory issue while inserting into Elasticsearch index using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, memory, aws-lambda

I am using python API to insert into elasticsearch cluster Index.

There is parent list  my_list_dict from which i am inserting into index

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()
my_list_dict = [{'id': '1', 'name': 'A'},
{'id': '2', 'name': 'B'},{'id': '3', 'name': 'C'}]
for each in my_list_dict:
 es.index(index='index_name', id=each['id'], body=each)
```

AWS code
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/indexing-metadata-in-amazon-elasticsearch-service-using-aws-lambda-and-python/

```
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection
session = boto3.session.Session()
credentials = session.get_credentials()
aws_auth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key,
                    credentials.secret_key,
                    session.region_name, 'es',
                    session_token=credentials.token)
es = Elasticsearch('https://vpc.xxxx.xom',
                                      http_auth=aws_auth,
                                      use_ssl=True,
                                      verify_certs=True,
                                      connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection)

my_list_dict = [{'id': '1', 'name': 'A'},
{'id': '2', 'name': 'B'},{'id': '3', 'name': 'C'}]
for each in my_list_dict:
 es.index(index='index_name', id=each['id'], body=each)
```

my_list_dict has increased to 50 MB now. Earlier I was able to insert the data successfully without any issue

Since list has increase size, `I am getting error Command failed out of memory` what is the way out for this?

[image]

`Do I need to write a generator expression for this? like form my_list_dict take first 100 items loop and insert into cluster then 100 items like that`

I was pushing the document from AWS lambda

Comment: Hi Sim, Is this elasticsearch exception ?

Comment: I was pushing the document from AWS lambda and AWS glue as well

Comment: @AshishTiwari I have added aws code as well

Comment: Need more details about error. Can you just paste the error as it is what is full exception ?